# python ConfigParser.NoSectionError: - not working on server

Tags: python-2.7, django-settings

Python 2.7
Django 1.10

settings.ini file(located at "/opts/myproject/settings.ini"):

```
[settings]
DEBUG: True
SECRET_KEY: '5a88V*GuaQgAZa8W2XgvD%dDogQU9Gcc5juq%ax64kyqmzv2rG'
```

On my django settings file I have:

```
import os
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser

config = RawConfigParser()
config.read('/opts/myproject/settings.ini')

SECRET_KEY = config.get('settings', 'SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = config.get('settings', 'DEBUG')
```

The setup works fine locally, but when I deploy to my server I get the following error if I try run any django management commands:

```
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'settings'
```

If I go into Python shell locally I type in the above imports and read the file I get back:

```
['/opts/myproject/settings.ini']
```

On server I get back:

```
[]
```

I have tried changing "confif.read()" to "config.readfp()" as suggested on here but it didn't work.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: What is in the server's `/opts/myproject/settings.ini`?

Comment: Do you have an `/opt/myproject/settings.ini` file on the server?

Comment: I mention that at start of message, the part starting [settings]

Comment: yes the file is 100% on the server and has the above settings section on it.

Comment: You mention, "locally" and "server". I assume you mean that you are trying to deploy this on a different machine. The behavior you see is consistent with a missing config file. That's why I'm asking what is on the server, not the local machine.

Comment: Yes I understand. Thanks for help. Yes I am deploying a website onto a prod server.

Comment: Just for giggles, you could add `assert '[settings]' in open('/opts/myproject/settings.ini').read()`. Perhaps its something simple like the settings file being in the more traditional `/opt` directory.

Comment: On server my "settings.ini" file was called "setting.ini". Your command helped, thanks for helping out.